# How to get continous call back when MKAnnotationView is dragged

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotationview, mapkit

I have `MKAnnotationView` which is drag able, and I have implemented `didChangeDragState:` delegate method for which I get callback at start and end of drag but not continuously. I want to track the current coordinate of annotation as it is dragged, please help me with some solution. Thank you.

Comment: Try using this method : 
`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate can be got from annotationview.coordinates  :

```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   
  didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:
  (MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
  {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCoordinates = view.annotation.coordinate;
  }
```

Comment: This method is only called when the drag state of the annotation view changes from one state to another, it won't be called continuously as the view is being dragged. It only gets called once when changing to the `Dragging` state. Additionally, the coordinate on the annotation is only updated when the state changes to `Ended`, and isn't updated while dragging.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't an Apple-provided way for you to do this, but you can achieve it through KVO (h/t to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918210/callback-when-dragging-annotation/22270868#22270868)).

You'll also need to manually determine the annotation view's coordinates, as the annotation's coordinates aren't updated until after it has entered `MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding`.

The full solution looks like this:

```
// Somewhere in your code before the annotation view gets dragged, subscribe your observer object to changes in the annotation view's frame center
annotationView.addObserver(DELEGATE_OBJECT, forKeyPath: "center", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

// Then in the observer's code, fill out the KVO callback method
// Your observer will need to conform to the NSKeyValueObserving protocol -- all `NSObject`s already do
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    // Check that we're observing an annotation view. The `where` clause can be omitted if you're only observing changes in its frame, or don't care about extra calls
    if let annotationView = object as? MKAnnotationView where keyPath == "center" {
        // Defined below, `coordinateForAnnotationView` converts a CGPoint measured within a given MKMapView to the geographical coordinate represented in that location
        let newCoordinate = coordinateForAnnotationView(pin, inMapView: self.mapView)

        // Do stuff with `newCoordinate`
    }
}

func coordinateForAnnotationView(annotationView: MKAnnotationView, inMapView mapView: MKMapView) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    // Most `MKAnnotationView`s will have a center offset, including `MKPinAnnotationView`
    let trueCenter = CGPoint(x: annotationView.center.x - annotationView.centerOffset.x,
        y: annotationView.center.y - annotationView.centerOffset.y)

    return mapView.convertPoint(trueCenter, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
}
```